# Flexslider startAt property - What's required?

Tags: wordpress, flexslider

I have flexslider working in a WordPress website with custom navigation. However, I can't get the startAt property to work. It always starts on the first slide. I've tried numerous modifications based on the Woo Flexslider page and what's on github. No luck.

Here's my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  jQuery(window).load(function() {
  jQuery(".flexslider").flexslider({
  slideshow: false, 
  controlNav: true, 
  directionNav: true, 
  controlsContainer: ".slider-controls",
  manualControls: ".flex-control-nav li",
  startAt: 3'
  });
});
</script>
```

Have I missed something?

Comment: That's pretty odd - the only thing that you are supposed to do is just enter an integer for the `startAt` property. Can you give us a demo link where this is not working?

Comment: Nikola: The content is confidential, although it's on a dev server available without a password to the page. Is there any way to get you the URL privately? I don't have a problem with the solution being posted. Or the link after the page is published next week.

Comment: The problem was solved by Nikola. I wasn't running the most recent version of Flexslider. It's always something simple. Thanks Nikola!